# Evenly dividing candy bar into $n$ pieces

Tags: recreational-mathematics, fair-division

I have 2 friends.  We have one candybar and we want to divide it evenly.  Unfortunately we don't have any way of accurately measuring and cutting the candybar.  Therefore we are looking for a method by which we can fairly divide the candybar.  If it was just me and one friend, it would be easy: I would divide ($D$) the candybar as evenly as possible into 2 and then pass ($P$) the candybar to my friend and let them choose ($C$).  (Thus, the whole method could be encoded as $DPC$.)  What method can I use for the current case?  What method can I use for the general case of me and $n-1$ friends?  How can I prove that the given method is fair?

Please reply soon.  I'm getting hungry.

*Also, feel free to retag my question. I didn't find a candybar tag.*

Comment: Can't you just buy two more candybars? (:

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at this [article on cake cutting](http://www.nyu.edu/gsas/dept/politics/faculty/brams/cake-cutting.pdf).

Comment: It's better to post at least a sketch of the solution here, because links can go dead.

Comment: Here's the *Notices of the AMS* paper: http://www.ams.org/notices/200611/fea-brams.pdf